# Hide 'div' tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I have JavaScript code that hides a tag when it is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.visibility="hidden";
```

Although when I do this, even though the div tag is hidden, there is still a space where the div tag is located. how do I collapse the whole div tag using JavaScript?

Comment: When you set the `visibility` property of an element to `hidden`, it's only invisible and it still takes up space in the layout, you should use `display = 'none'` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: @tristo Are you trying to remove it entirely? Can you put together an example on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 7):

You should use:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none";
```

---

Just to mention that `getElementById()` will be looking for a `div` with the id of `div`, I suggest you change this to something more obvious, an example would be:

```
<div id="container"><!--Content--></div>
```

Then your JavaScript could be:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
```

Check [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm) to see what the difference is between `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`

Comment: mind case sensitivity... document.getelementbyid is not the same as document.getElementById

Comment: After changing 'id' to "Id" it works fine. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
 document.getelementById("div_id").style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("yourdivID").style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById("divID").style.display = "none";
```

OR

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.display = "none";
```

**NOTE: `document.getElementById()` only select the elements having `id` attributes.**